# My Pull Request has a code that I haven't written

Tags: git, github

My Pull Request on GitHub:

- 1 my commit
- Merge branch master
- 2 my commit
- Merge branch master
- 3 my commit

In the meantime another person added Pull Request and was merge to the master

Now, finally, he shows me part of his code in my PR

It's like I made a code that was in another PR written by another person

Is there any way for me to separate my commits and put them back on the newest master?

Comment: Try: Make new branch from up-to-date master. Cherry-pick just your 3 commits to it, one-by-one and fixing issues etc.  Create a new pr from that.

Comment: The reason you see his commits is probably because his PR got merged to master before you merged master to your PR, so when you did so, all commits in master not in your PR, including his, got merged in your PR.

Answer (score 0):

Your commits should be on your cloned copy of the original git repro. 
For this cloned copy, you can allow yourself "forced push".  (github settings, branches, new rule, allow forced push)

"rebase" your commits (locally):

```
git checkout yourbranch
git rebase -i master
```

In the editor (that will be shown) pick only your commits, skip all merges.
Then force push your branch.

```
git push --force-with-lease
```